# After grouping, cannot get dplyr's slice to select top 3 of each grouping

Tags: r, dplyr, slice

I am trying to only retain the top 3 records from each grouping based on l5_ppg_max. This code sets up the table correctly, but when I add the slice code it doe not select top 3 records of each group.

```
#library(reticulate)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(janitor)
library(readxl)
library(reprex)

player_projection <- read_csv("DFF_NHL_cheatsheet.csv", col_names = TRUE)

team__reg_line <- player_projection %>%
    clean_names() %>%
    mutate_if(is.numeric, ~replace_na(., 0)) %>%
    filter(!position == "G") %>%
    filter(!reg_line  == 0) %>%
    select(team, reg_line, l5_ppg_max, salary) %>%
    arrange(team, reg_line, desc(l5_ppg_max)) %>%
    group_by(team, reg_line, salary, l5_ppg_max)
```

When I add this line:

```
 slice_head(n = 3)
```

It still returns all records.

Also tried top_n(3), but read it was deprecated so stayed with dplyr slice functions.  Quite easy to do in excel manually, but need to do in R for ggplot outputs.

Comment: I found the problem,  I needed use dplyr::slice to my added code.  Plotly library was loaded along with tidyverse(dplyr) and they both have slice functions. The order must have selected the plotly function first rather than the dplyr slice function.  Runs fine now it but took a day to figure it out....

Comment: You can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of only leaving a comment - especially if you think a full answer will help future visitors with a similar problem.